# Specman e: Handling unexpected end of test

Tags: specman

I'm looking for the function that handles unexpected end of tests and can't seem to find it.
I know there should be one, because system errors (os11, for example) and debug aborts are handled by Specman.

We're using semaphores when running several tests in parallel, but whenever a test doesn't end properly due to a system error or during debug sessions, the function that frees the semaphore isn't executed, forcing us to manually release it and sometimes to completely restart Specview.
I need to find a function (or functions) that can be extended so I can add the code that releases the semaphore to them.

Thanks!

Comment: I got a patch from Cadence because there's no support for my case. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specman has no handler for aborted debug sessions. Cadence issued a patch that might find its way to future releases.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for "configure run error_command=command_string". In the string you can call any method.

The problem is that though it is called for most mentioned cases, including os11 handled by Specman, it might not be called for some other real-life cases, like unhandled exceptions, critical exceptions handled by another tool, fatal errors, signal -9, etc.

So "config run" can significantly improve you situation, but will not give you a solution for the cases that Specman doesn't handle gracefully. For that you probably need some control mechanism outside of Specman.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't answer my needs. I implemented a function to run on error_command, but it doesn't get invoked when aborting a debug session, which is the most common case I need to handle.

Comment: It seems that such flow is a little special. There is no documented hook for abort command, and when Specman is closed after that, none of other other hooks seem to be called. How debug session is aborted in your flow? Can you use custom command instead of 'abort'? Or maybe it is possible to define 'abort' macro, which will be called instead of built-in 'abort' command, call the release function and after then call the original command?

Comment: A macro/function will solve my problem when people use the command line when aborting debug in Specview, but it won't help if they use the GUI abort button.

Comment: Hmmm, it might be that there is no good solution for that case. I suggest to contact Cadence support, they might provide you an acceptable workaround/solution.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for abort, you can also workaround it with a macro, for example:

```
define <my_abort'command> "my_abort" as {
    specman("do_my_special_things()");
    specman("abort");
};
```

it won't help with the GUI button, but typing `my_abort` from the command prompt will do it.

Comment: This is the same answer I got in the comments of the previous answer. I contacted Cadence support and got a patch because there's no support for my needs. Thanks all anyways.